# Resumé Parsing in .Net framework using Natural Language Processing

Tags: c#, .net, nlp

I'm trying to compare two resumés. I have a criteria that if certain fields match it is a duplicate. As you may know, resumé styles differ. How do I understand that the name field is a name field, so I can store it somewhere and compare it with the same field in another resumé?

As of now I have used an Interop method and I am getting all document content in a string. From the string I am splitting on all the \t, \r and empty spaces, and getting an array. From the array, how can I get my own standard xml format like below:

**XML Format:**

```
 <CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME>CandidateName here</CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME>
 <CANDIDATE_FIRST_NAME>CandidateFirstName here</CANDIDATE_FIRST_NAME>
 <CANDIDATE_LAST_NAME>CandidateLastName here</CANDIDATE_LAST_NAME>
 <PRIMARY_EMAI`enter code here`L_ID>name@gmail.com</PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID>
 <PHONE_BASIC>+919720018454155</PHONE_`enter code here`BASIC>
 <DOB>8/2/1987</DOB>
 <STREET1></STREET1>
 <STREET2></STREET2>
 <CITY></CITY>
 <REGION></REGION>
 <COUNTRY></COUNTRY>
 <PIN></PIN>
```

After reviewing my questions it's obvious to me that I have no idea what I'm doing and a starting point would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ganesh, 
I recommend to build your own logic.
Here is what you can use.

1. Get all resumes divided into fields.
2. And then you can give weight-age to each field like.

   ```
   Email - 80
   Phone - 80 
   Name - 20 
   Highest Education - 20
   Home city   -  20 
   Last companies worked - 20 
   DOB - 30 
   and others
   ```
3. Then add the numbers and see if their sum is 80 or above.
4. If more than that, then you can say its same resume.
5. But if not then you know what.
6. Challenge is how many fields, and how you split them. I recommend use some resume parser and build logic over and above that.